# Trouble in using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to make an app which is using parse library for push notifications.I followed the tutorials from parse.com but its not working.
I am getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.robotrackerclient/com.robotrackerclient.MainActivity}: 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: listener==null
```

I think the problem is in the code.I am having a main activity which is launching activity of the app.I am putting the **parse.initialize()** code in the onCreate method of main activity.Is this creating the problem? There is one more error: You must call **parse.initialize(..)** before using the parse library.

The Main Activity is just a simple class getting the lattitude and longitude of the current location and pushing it.

```
         public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         private String imei_code_of_device;
         private LocationManager lm;
         private LocationListener locationListener;
         TelephonyManager mngr;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.
        //PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        Parse.initialize(this, "APP_KEY", "CLIENT_KEY"); 
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

        mngr=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei_code_of_device=mngr.getDeviceId();
        lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);               

        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        if ( !lm.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
        else{

         lm.requestLocationUpdates(
         LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
         10000,
         0,
         locationListener);
         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10000,0,locationListener);              

        }
        }
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

         final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                           startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                ParseObject po=new ParseObject("LatLang");
                po.put("imei_code",imei_code_of_device);
                po.put("latitude",loc.getLatitude());
                po.put("longitude",loc.getLongitude());
                po.saveInBackground();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() +" Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

     }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my androidmenifest file:
I completed these steps with help of the tutorials available on parse.com.I included everything which parse.com tutorial said me to include.I am not getting the point of Application.Because I have to parse in the one of the activities only and it is not the first activity to be launched.So I dont want to initialize parse at my application startup.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.robotrackerclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <permission android:name="com.robotrackerclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.robotrackerclient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.robotrackerclient" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>            
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
         </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

       </application>
        </manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay thank you very much for helping I am able to send push to parse.com.The mistake was in the manifest file.I updated the menifestfile with providing android:name=."ParseActivity" under the application tag.Then I defined the initialization in the ParseActivity class.
Now can anybody tell how to get the pushed data over server back on another device using the same set of keys?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your app and client keys instead of default values `APP_KEY` and `CLIENT_KEY` in this line:
`Parse.initialize(this, "APP_KEY", "CLIENT_KEY");`

which you can get after signing up at Parse.

Comment: I did this .I got the keys from parse.com